# Accessing a public var in a subclass in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm trying to understand OOP better.

I just want to trace a public var from baseclass in a subclass. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in the way I wrote the code. Can you tell why? And how can you do it to make it work?

The baseclass:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public var myvar:String = 'hello world'; 

        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }       
}
```

The subclass:

```
package  {
    import Main;

    public class Subclass extends Main {

        public function Subclass()  {
            trace(myvar); //it doesn't outputs anything
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the entry point to this code? I only see the class definitions, and no code to execute. I don't know this language, but you should somewhere create an instance of Succlass if you want the corresponding code to be executed.

Comment: The main class is the document class, and i want to extend the main class in the subclass.

Comment: And what is executed here? Which line executes the code??

Comment: You are not calling the constructor of the Subclass, why should it ouput anything? ;)

Comment: I just want to call myvar in subclass

Comment: Should there be an instance of subclass in main?

Comment: There should SOMWEWHERE be an instance of Subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trace a var (which has been declared in the baseclass) in the subclass then you have to create an instance of the subclass in another class, e.g. the main class. The code looks like this:

The main class:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import Subclass;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        private var subclass = new Subclass();

        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }
}
```

The baseclass:

```
package  {

    public class Baseclass {
        public var myvar = "hello world";

        public function Baseclass() {
        }
    }
}
```

The subclass:

```
package  {

    public class Subclass extends Baseclass{

        public function Subclass()  {
            trace(myvar); //console output: hello world
        }
    }
}
```